# Как ввести логин и пароль от github с помощью скрипта bash

Tags: linux, windows, git, bash

Как ввести логин и пароль от github при выполнении команды ***git push*** из bash-скрипта?
Также интересует любой другой способ, для обхода ввода пароля и логина при выполнении данной команды.

Answer (score 2):

устанавливаете **ssh**, генерируете себе **ssh** ключ, регистрируете свой открытый ключ на сайте **github**. создаёте подключение для удобства в

~/.ssh/config

```
host github.com
  HostName имя_подключения
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_имя_закрытого_ключа
  User git
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

создаёте удалённый проект

`> git remote add имя_удалёнки имя_подключения:/удалённый_путь/имя_проекта.git`

после настройки делаете

`> git push имя_удалёнки ...`